# I getting xml parsing error only when running jar file and not when using Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, jar, executable-jar

I have Java program that is doing some XML parsing of a file and it works fine when I run it from Eclipse.

But when I try to build an excutable jar file and run it, I am getting XML validation errors. 
I even disabled all validation in my java files.
Any ideas of what may be causing this???

I am just building the jar from the java files with a manifest that has been used before.

Any ideas!!!!

Comment: Did you check that your executable jar is packing the necessary jars to parse the xml into it? Most likely you are leaving them out.

Comment: I will double check when I get to work tomorrow,  If I am not including my xml parser jar, would I get this error?? What jar file do I need?

Comment: Well, I guess you said up above that you got xml validation errors, but I just assumed that nothing was really working regarding xml parsing in general. If you post your stacktrace, it will be easier for the group to help you.

Comment: You're running different code or parsing a different file, or both.

Comment: I am running the same code with the same XML files. the only difference is one was a built jar and the other is in eclipse